# Asynchronous threads race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have been asked to run a task with two **asynchronous** threads. One that is supposed to move a vehicle and the other calculates and plots the area covered by the vehicle. A simplification of the code is the following:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <math.h> 
#include <chrono>

using namespace std; 


class Robot {

    private:
        bool moving;
        vector<double> position;
        double area_covered;

    public:
        Robot(const vector<double> &initial_position) {
            moving = true;
            position = initial_position;
            area_covered = 0.0;
        }


        void get_area() {
            static vector<double> previous_measure = this->position; // initialized with the first position the robot is in

            while (this->moving) {
                this->area_covered += sqrt(pow(this->position[0] - previous_measure[0]) + pow(this->position[1] - previous_measure[1]));
                previous_measure = this->position; // save the new position for the next iteration
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(600)); // sleep for 600 ms
            }
        }


        void move_robot(const vector<vector<double> > &map) {
            for (int i=1; i < map.size(); i++) {
                this->position = map[i];
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500)); // sleep for 500 ms
            }
            this->moving = false;
        }
};
  


int main () {
    vector<vector<double> > path{
      {0.0359, -0.013}, {0.0658, -0.0287},  {0.0736, -0.027}};
    
    Robot r3(path[0]);
    auto thread1 = std::async(&Robot::move_robot, &r3, path);
    auto thread2 = std::async(&Robot::get_area, &r3);
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

In method `get_area()` I am using multiple times `this.position` which may differ because it is changed in the other thread. I cannot block the other thread while doing `get_area` but I must avoid using different `this.position` in one loop run. The easiest solution is to create another variable to save the initial value of `this.position` but **I would like to know from you whether there is a better C++ way to do it**. It would be something like:

```
        void get_area() {
            static vector<double> previous_measure = this->position; // initialized with the first position the robot is in
            vector<double> auxiliar;

            while (this->moving) {
                auxiliar = this->position;
                this->area_covered += sqrt(pow(auxiliar[0] - previous_measure[0]) + pow(auxiliar[1] - previous_measure[1]));
                previous_measure = auxiliar; // save the new position for the next iteration
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(600)); // sleep for 600 ms
            }
        }
```

Moreover, **I need to notify `get_area()` when the method / thread of `move_robot()` finishes so that in the next while iteration it quits as well**. Right now I am using the attribute `moving` but doing so I am checking the condition before each iteration and not at the end. I could add an `if` at the end to check it but there should be some better approaches.

Last, I would appreciate as well your opinion on **how to cleanly pass the object to the two asynchronous threads and wait for them to solve the C++ way**.

Comment: there is no reason to use multithread in your example.

Comment: but alternatively, you can push `position`s to a queue and process it from another thread.

Comment: It is mandatory for me to do that. It is an exercise

Answer (score 2):

This is code is very unsafe and filled with UB and syntax errors.

- You cannot write to memory from one thread and read it from another without synchronization.
- Declaring `timespan` variable does not put the thread to sleep.
- What happens if `get_area` does not get called at all while `move_robot` is iterating? Unlikely but it is also very unlikely to get 1:1 mapping.
- Sleep is not a synchronization primitive.
- `this.` is always wrong syntax.
- `std::async` does not return a thread but `std::future` instead.

Do some research on threading in C++ - [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) can also serve as a good tutorial with its examples.

You should rewrite the code with `std::atomic<T>` for primitive types like `this->moving`, and locking for others. Of course only if they are accessed from multiple threads and are not naturally thread-safe.

Because you require 1:1 mapping, use 1 producer, 1 consumer queue with `std::condition_variable`:

- `move_robot` will push to the queue and notify the consumer.
- `get_area` will wait on the notification, process enqueued elements and go back to sleep.
- You can add a *poison pill* to the queue to signal `get_area` that the work is done.
- Spawn both threads in main and wait on them.

Comment: Thanks @Quimby , I have edited the `this.`  and the sleeps. Does your method work as well if both threads refresh at different frecuencies? Imagine I want get area to be called every second but the robots moves every 0.1 second

Comment: @HectorEsteban Why would you want to do that? Then the area won't be correct. Forget that, you cannot use `sleep` or any other primitive to give threads frequencies. "Call something every X seconds" requires real-time kernel, something you most like do not use or have. Instead you should design your program around synchronization points, not time. If you want more specific help, please specify your requirements exactly.

Comment: I was using sleeps because I want to simulate the movement of the robot and to make the program to not instantly finish, in order to see the results how are progressing. I have added `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(600));` which I think is the correct way. One last question @Quimby , could you add a toy example with what you mean by using std:atomic with attribute moving and locking? I have never seen object attributes declared as atomic. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Moreover. Using your approach, `get_area` could block the method `move_robot` while is calculating the area isn't it? And I do not want that

Comment: @HectorEsteban Please read about threading, it is not a topic I can summarize in one answer. You can just add `std::atomic<bool> moving;` member variable, not sure what you want to see. No, the methods would block each other only if both access the queue at the same time. So `get_area` will only block during its `queue.pop()`, not the whole call.  Again, read about threading concepts and consumer-producer queues. Also please realize that `move_robot` is arbitrarily interrupted and blocked by the scheduler anyway. Using sleep as delay is OK.